# Error 1004 when trying to add a pagebreak from macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that we create using POI, but POI causes some issue whenever I try to set a page break using it. So we've just resorted to setting a specific string in the first column of each row that we want a page break and resorting to a macro to replace that string with a page break. However, whenever I run it I get the error:

```
Run-time error '1004': unable to set the PageBreak property of the Range class
```

The macro we're using is:

```
Sub testPrintBreak()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "EMY-REPLACE WITH PAGE BREAK-EMY" Then
            Cells(i, 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

We also tried another one:

```
Sub InsertPageBreaksByKeyphrase()
    Dim rangeSelection As Range
    Dim cellCurrent As Range

    Set rangeSelection = Application.Selection
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

    For Each cellCurrent In rangeSelection
        If cellCurrent.Value = "EMY-REPLACE WITH PAGE BREAK-EMY" Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(cellCurrent.Row + 1).PageBreak = _
                xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next cellCurrent
End Sub
```

Which gave the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because that's not how you would add it.

Try this:

```
Sub testPrintBreak()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = "EMY-REPLACE WITH PAGE BREAK-EMY" Then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cells(i, 1)
         End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Edit: This is just for curiosity, does this work?

```
Sub testPrintBreak()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "EMY-REPLACE WITH PAGE BREAK-EMY" Then
            ws.Cells(i, 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Interestingly, the OP's original code works for me.  (But the macro recorder generates your sort of code.)

Comment: @YowE3K - Hmm, interesting.  It works exactly as he posted? You don't need to clarify the worksheet `Cells()` is on perhaps?  Maybe OP didn't have the same worksheet Active when that line got called? Hm, and yeah I used the MacroRecorder to get what I posted.

Comment: @EricB - Can you do a quick favor? I just added a second code, can you run that and see if it works? Or do you still get the same error?

Comment: Well.... I did change `"EMY-REPLACE WITH PAGE BREAK-EMY"` to `"a"` for my testing but, other than that, no changes.  The OP is working on ActiveSheet, so the unqualified `Cells` didn't have an impact.  The only problem with it (and with your code) is the use of `UsedRange.Rows.Count` which is only a good thing to do if `UsedRange` starts at row 1 (it should be `UsedRange.Rows(UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row` if it doesn't start at row 1).

Comment: @YowE3K - Agreed about `UsedRange`, but I figure the crux of his question was adding the page break, not getting the incorrect range.

Comment: Agreed - I only mentioned it because (a) it was the **only** problem I had, and (b) it had me scratching my head for a while when my test data had an "a" in rows 10, 25, 40 and 45 but the last two didn't generate a page break :D

Comment: @BruceWayne same issue when I try the new code, run time error 1004 unable to set the PageBreak property of the range class. As a side note (if it helps) I'm using excel 2016